# Traversing though list, if object string is not on the list then return null

Tags: java

Let's say I have 7 muppets on my list. They all have names (strings). The program returns the muppet (object) if their name is on the list. Now the problem is that how do I return null if none of the 7 muppets on my list match the parameter `name`? I know how to return null with the head node by simply returning null if the head node name is equal to null. But how do I do that with the rest of the list?

```
public Muppet peek(String name) {
    if(start == null) { // if the start Muppet is equal to null, so there's nothing on the list
        return null;
    }
    if(start.getName().equals(name)) {   // return the muppet at the start of the list
        return start;
    } else  {
        Muppet previous = start;
        while(!previous.getNext().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) { // traverse through the whole list
            previous = previous.getNext();
        }
        Muppet current = previous.getNext();
        return current; // Return the muppet that was asked
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactely do you mean by List? Do you have a java List<Muppet>? Is this your own datacollection where you store head and next? For 1) you can use java's streams API and filter and map or in case 2) call the next node recursively until you are at the end (next == null) and then return

Comment: Paste entire code.

Comment: @ZahidKhan Not the entire code. A [mcve]. Big difference. Never tell new users to post ALL code.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of linked list works well with recursion, and recursive solutions are sometimes simpler than iterative ones. Plus, since the recursion occurs at the end of the method the compiler may well optimize it to use a loop anyway.

```
public Muppet peek(String name) {
    return find(start, name);
}

private Muppet find(Muppet head, String name) {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (head.getName().equals(name)) {
        return head;
    }
    return find(head.getNext(), name);
}
```

Comment: That is not really answering the question. It is perfectly fair (and even better, depending on context) to use an iterative solution, instead of recursion. The OP asks about how to do something using a loop, what is the point of telling him to use recursion?!

Comment: Because this kind of linked list works well with recursion. I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Well, unless your lists get really large, and recursion gets you into the stack overflow range. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

A simple iterative solution could look like this:

```java
public Muppet peek(String name) {
    Muppet current = start;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getName().equals(name)) { // or equalsIgnoreCase
            break;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return current;
}
```